# Infinitely looping background in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the sprites for everything in place. I’m trying to create a parallax effect but everything I find online relies on a moving camera, and I have a fixed camera.  Would I do something with Mathf:repeat?

Comment: The effect seems to rely on the thing moving a different speed relative to *something* What do you want the parallax effect to be relative towards? Here is a simple solution for a webpage: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: Does your background consist of multiple layers? If so, are you trying to create a parallax effect by moving the multiple background layers?